# Unable to fix PDO Invalid parameter number in building up a dynamic sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have been trying to fix the `Invalid parameter number` on the following PDO code without success. I have narrowed it down to the two foreach loops from `$tid` that generate dynamic fields and parameters because the code works when commenting out all of the parts that relate to `$tid`. But still, from the look of the output I can't figure out what's wrong with the loops. Can anyone see what's the problem?

PDO code:

```
   try 
   {
      $comma = "";
      $tno = "";
      $c = "1";
      foreach($tid as $t)   
      { 

        $tno .= "{$comma}tno_{$c}";
        $tno_sql .= "{$comma}(SELECT tno from `model` WHERE model_no = :model_no{$c})";
        $tno_update .= "{$comma}tno_{$c} = :model_no1{$c}";
        $c++;
        $comma = ",";
      }

      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename", $username, $password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql = "

     INSERT INTO `aid` (user_id,$tno,content,title,budget_min,budget_max,style) 
     VALUES (
             (SELECT id from `users` WHERE user_id = :user_id1),
              $tno_sql,:content1,:title1,:budget_min1,:budget_max1,:style1)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            $tno_update,content = :content2, title = :title2,budget_min = :budget_min2,
            budget_max  = :budget_max2,style = :style2
            ";
            $users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $users->bindValue(':user_id1',$_SESSION["user_id"]);

            $users->bindValue(':content1', $content);
            $users->bindValue(':content2', $content);

            $users->bindValue(':style1', $style);
            $users->bindValue(':style2', $style);

            $users->bindValue(':budget_min1', $budget_min);
            $users->bindValue(':budget_min2', $budget_min);

            $users->bindValue(':budget_max1',$budget_max);
            $users->bindValue(':budget_max2', $budget_max);

            $users->bindValue(':title1', $title);
            $users->bindValue(':title2', $title);

            $i = 1;         
            foreach ($tid as $t) { 
              $users->bindValue(':model_no{$i}', $t);
              $users->bindValue(':model_no1{$i}', $t);  
              print "':model_no{$i}',";
              print "':model_no1{$i}',";

              $i++;

            }

           $users->execute();
           $dbh = null;
   }
```

Comment: I don't see it either... What does `$dbh->errorInfo()` say?

Comment: @Rudie , Should `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` be put before `$dbh = null;`? All I got was `Array( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Yes, immediately after `execute();`. If it's empty, that's not where the error comes from. Any other queries going on?

Comment: Also, check out [debugDumpParams](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php).

Comment: @Rudie, I have updated the output from `debugDumpParams`, it looks like the loop only generates two `bindValue` instead of six, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  $users->bindValue(':model_no{$i}', $t);
  $users->bindValue(':model_no1{$i}', $t);
```

to

```
  $users->bindValue(":model_no$i", $t);
  $users->bindValue(":model_no1$i", $t);
```

String interpolation only happens when the values are within double-quotes.

Comment: Good catch! @RedGiant You can see in the debug output: `:model_no{$i}`